# Using R and ggplot2 how do I create a graph with multiple columns

Tags: r, ggplot2

My `R` data frame (`electronics`) look like this:

```
date                  manufacture    price
2019-11-22 11:30:04   Apple          600.00
2019-01-16 01:74:14   Samsung        877.00
2019-07-12 04:23:31   Apple          925.00
2019-07-12 01:21:54   Apple          1200.00
2019-01-16 04:48:34   Samsung        1100.00
2019-07-12 12:20:22   Apple          1450.00    
2019-03-28 06:23:11   Apple          1250.00
```

What I want to do are the following:

- Take the `sum` of `price` for each given day (`date`) and create a chart to see the `sale` of each `Manufacture` by `date`
- `date` is going to be on `x-axis` and line plot that has the price of manufacture
- Basically I want to see the chart sum of sales overtime per the manufacture.

**What did I do?**

```
ggplot(electronics,
   aes(date,sum(price))) +
   geom_point() + 
   geom_smooth(method="lm") +
   facet_grid(manufacture)
```

However, it seems like I am not getting proper chart. Please kindly help me solve this. Thank you!

Comment: Aggregate your data before plotting.

Comment: you're missing a `~` in `facet_grid(~manufacture)`

Comment: @zx8754 is it not possible to do in real-time? How do I do aggregate by `Date` and price first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried the following according to your data:

```
library(tidyverse)
electronics <- data.frame(date = c("2019-11-22 11:30:04",
"2019-01-16 01:74:14", "2019-07-12 04:23:31",
"2019-07-12 01:21:54", "2019-01-16 04:48:34",
"2019-07-12 12:20:22", "2019-03-28 06:23:11"), 
manufacture = c("Apple","Samsung","Apple","Apple",
"Samsung","Apple","Apple"), 
price = c(600,877,925,1200,1100,1450,1250))

electronics$date <- as.Date(electronics$date)

electronics %>% group_by(date,manufacture) %>% 
summarise(sum = sum(price)) %>% ggplot(aes(date,sum)) + 
geom_point() + geom_smooth(method="lm") + facet_grid(~manufacture)
```

As per your question and observation I have edited the code so now you can aggregate with "group_by", in this case by date and manufacture. After that, you summarise the sum of the prices.

[image]

Hope it helps. Regards,

Alexis

Comment: I am supposed to take the `sum` of price and then group by `date`. I do not think you did the `sum` for each day.

Comment: Hello @floss, I have edited my answer, so now its grouped by date and manufacture, and summarised with the sum function. Hope it helps.